# Pass inputs to composed Angular directives

Tags: angular

I use a third-party directive "A" that takes several inputs: a1, a2.

I want to create another directive "B" that would become a facade for directive "A", with specifying some specific values to directive "A", so that I don't have to configure its inputs every time I use directive "A". The values will be defined/calculated and encapsulated by directive "B".

So, instead of doing:

```
<div a a1="something" a2="somethingElse"></div>
```

I want to do:

```
<div b></div>
```

I see there's a [directive composition API](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api) in Angular 15. But I can't find a way to encapsulate underlying directives inputs anywhere.

Creating a wrapper component does not work for me, as I want B to be exactly an attribute directive, so that it does not create unnecessary DOM nesting.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider directive A has the following code:

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[a]', standalone: true })
export class A implements OnInit {
  @Input() a1: string = '';
  @Input() a2: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Logging in Directive A:');
    console.log({ a1: this.a1, a2: this.a2 });
  }
}
```

You can use `hostDirectives` in directive `B` and pass values for `A's` inputs:

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { A } from './a.directive';

@Directive({ selector: '[b]', standalone: true, hostDirectives: [A] })
export class B {
  constructor(a: A) {
    a.a1 = 'a1 from directive B';
    a.a2 = 'a2 from directive B';
  }
}
```

And you won't end up with additional DOM elements.

Checkout the full example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lbtd1u?file=src%2Fdirectives%2Fb.directive.ts)